# Excel Formula for SUMIFS for calculated date range

Tags: excel-formula

I've setup a family budget/cashflow and I'm trying to write a formula so I can look at particular weekly periods and see how well we've tracked in terms of savings.

Essentially I have a process date column, a number of columns for the transactions in our various accounts.

At each pay I'd like to look at the sum of all the accounts for the past 7 days to see if we've spent more than the pay or not.

I thought I could use SUMIFS to do this based upon the research I've done.  I have the following formula but Excel complains it has an error and I don't know where?

Any help is appreciated!

```
SUMIFS(Table1[[Savings Amount]:[Holiday Savings]],[Process Date], ">" Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]]-7, [Process Date],"<=" Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]])
```

Comment: You should also consider using a pivot table for this. You can use it to group by weeks.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you the results you would like but it is horrible and I'm afraid I have not attempted to simplify it because I am not sure it meets your requirement, though I hope it may be *some* help with the syntax:

```
=SUMIFS([Savings Amount],[Process Date],"<="&Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]])+SUMIFS([Holiday Savings],[Process Date],"<="&Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]])-SUMIFS([Savings Amount],[Process Date],"<"&Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]]-6)-SUMIFS([Holiday Savings],[Process Date],"<"&Table1[[#This Row],[Process Date]]-6)
```

Comment: I've managed to tweak your formula to work i my scenario.  There were some additional accounts I had to add, as I was doing a range of columns in my initial formula so it only showed the names of the first and last columns.  I'd be interested to understand what is wrong with the syntax of my initial formula, as the excel preview seems to correctly identify the different parts, it just seems to be unable to identify the columns after the first SUMIF statement.